How to update a chart in Google Slides dynamically?
I am trying to update the chart dynamically that is embedded in a Google Slides, but it throws an error at me.
This is the function that I came up with to replace some specific text that is placed in my base Google slide.
 public function getGoogleDrivePdf($fileId, $substitutions)
{
    $client = $this->getGoogleClient();
    $driveService = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $slidesService = new \Google_Service_Slides($client);
    $copy = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
        'name' => $substitutions['student_name'] . ' presentation',
    ]);
    $driveResponse = $driveService->files->copy($fileId, $copy);
    $slideFileId = $driveResponse->id;
    $requests = [];
    foreach ($substitutions as $key => $value) {
        $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Slides_Request(
            [
                'replaceAllText' => [
                    'containsText' => [
                        'text' => '{{'.$key.'}}',
                        'matchCase' => true
                    ],
                    'replaceText' => $value
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

$requests[] = new \Google_Service_Slides_Request(
        [
            'createSheetsChart' => [
                'spreadsheetId' => 'N_St1Lm-oxd4aWOjQ6o.......',
                'chartId' => ...040....,
                'linkingMode' => 'NOT_LINKED_IMAGE',
                'elementProperties' => [
                    'pageObjectId' => '.....9fd6d_.....',
                    'size' => [
                        'height' => $emu4M,
                        'width' => $emu4M
                    ],
                    'transform' => [
                        'scaleX' => 1,
                        'scaleY' => 1,
                        'translateX' => 100000,
                        'translateY' => 100000,
                        'unit' => 'EMU'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );

    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Slides_BatchUpdatePresentationRequest([
        'requests' => $requests,
    ]);
    $updateResponse = $slidesService->presentations->batchUpdate($slideFileId, $batchUpdateRequest);
    $response = $driveService->files->export(
        $slideFileId,
        'application/pdf',
        [
            'alt' => 'media',
        ]
    );

    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $driveService->files->delete($slideFileId);
    // Download
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $substitutions['slide_filename'] . '"');
    $response->setContent($content);

    return $response;
}

This function replaces the text I want that are in the Google Slide and downloads the slide as a PDF file without an issue.
But, now I want to add a chart to the slide and change the chart values dynamically. I tried to accomplish this by changing the values in source Google Sheet to replaceable text but It throws me this error.

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid requests[9].createSheetsChart: The specified chart could not be found in the spreadsheet.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Invalid requests[9].createSheetsChart: The specified chart could not be found in the spreadsheet.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

Any idea how to fix this or any workarounds?

About now I want to add a chart to the slide and change the chart values dynamically. I tried to accomplish this by changing the values in source Google Sheet to replaceable text but It throws me this error., can you provide your current script?

@Tanaike - I updated the code and and error. I am referring this page https://developers.google.com/slides/api/guides/add-chart#php

Thank you for replying. From your updated script, I understood that you wanted to insert a new chart from Spreadsheet to Slide. Here, can I ask you about the details of the relationship between your updated script and change the chart values dynamically? By the way, I think that the error of The specified chart could not be found in the spreadsheet." is due to the chart ID is not found in the Spreadsheet. So, I cannot still understand your expected result. Can I ask you about the details of it?

For example, do you want to simply refresh the chart inserted from Spreadsheet on Google Slide by Google Slides API? I cannot understand dynamically you expect. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Students of the site should be able to download the report. So the report text as well as the chart data should be changed depending on the student downloading the report.
In my Google slides, I have set the replaceable text like {{this_is_replace_text_1}}.  Also I added a chart so I can change the data dynamically, but it doesn't work.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my very poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand dynamically of Also I added a chart so I can change the data dynamically, but it doesn't work.. Can I ask you about the details of dynamically you expect? In your situation, do you want to replace a placeholder on the Slide with a chart on the Spreadsheet and refresh the chart? Or, do you want to refresh the existing chart on Slide?

As an example, user1 has scored marks 40% for the exam and user2 has scored 80%. When each user views/downloads the report, I want to display the marks in a chart (user will only see their marks in the chart)

Finally, after many many searches I found the solution.
First you have to update the Google Sheet values that sources the graph from a separate request prior to doing anything with the presentation/Google Slide.
Following is my function to update the Google Sheet values.
/**
 * @param $sheetId - Example: loi973hhbshbh3gf3f765f
 * @param $valueNrange  - Example: [['range' => 'A1', 'value' => '20']]
 * @param $valueInputOption - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption
 */
public function updateGoogleSheetValues ($sheetId, $valueNrange, $valueInputOption = "RAW") {

    try {
        $client = $this->getGoogleClient();
        $driveService = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $sheetsService = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
        $data = [];

        foreach ($valueNrange as $dataItem) {
            $data[] = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
                'range' => $dataItem['range'],
                'values' => [[$dataItem['value']]]
            ]);
        }

        $dataBody = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
            'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption,
            'data' => $data
        ]);

        $result = $sheetsService->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($sheetId, $dataBody);
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

After the Google Sheet values are updated, you can refresh the graph/chart in the presentation/Google Slide and download.
Following is my function to refresh the chart and download the slide as PDF.
public function getGoogleSlidesPdf($fileId, $substitutions, $elementOptions = [])
{
    $client = $this->getGoogleClient();
    $driveService = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $slidesService = new \Google_Service_Slides($client);
    $copy = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
        'name' => $substitutions['student_name'] . ' presentation',
    ]);
    $driveResponse = $driveService->files->copy($fileId, $copy);
    $certificateFileId = $driveResponse->id;
    $requests = [];
    $emu4M = ['magnitude' => 4000000, 'unit' => 'EMU'];
    foreach ($substitutions as $key => $value) {
        $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Slides_Request(
            [
                'replaceAllText' => [
                    'containsText' => [
                        'text' => '{{'.$key.'}}',
                        'matchCase' => true
                    ],
                    'replaceText' => $value
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
    
    $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Slides_Request([
        'refreshSheetsChart' => [
            'objectId' => 'g*********_0_0'
        ]
    ]);

    
    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Slides_BatchUpdatePresentationRequest([
        'requests' => $requests,
    ]);

    $updateResponse = $slidesService->presentations->batchUpdate($certificateFileId, $batchUpdateRequest);

    // uncomment the below line and set a breakpoint to find the "objectId" of chart or object from sheet objects if the chart or object is moved or edited (move front or back)
    // because the "objectId" will change when the chart or element is moved
    //$presentationObjects = $slidesService->presentations->get($certificateFileId);

    $response = $driveService->files->export(
        $certificateFileId,
        'application/pdf',
        [
            'alt' => 'media',
        ]
    );

    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $driveService->files->delete($certificateFileId);
    // Download
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $substitutions['certification_filename'] . '"');
    $response->setContent($content);

    return $response;
}

